# Golang Slice of custom Type in another Type as reference

Tags: reference, go

I get this error with my Go test code:

```
$ go run test.go 
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:43: cannot use &ol1 (type *Orderline) as type Orderline in array element
./test.go:43: cannot use &ol2 (type *Orderline) as type Orderline in array element
```

**Code**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Customer struct {
    Id int64
    Name string
}

type Order struct {
    Id int64
    Customer *Customer
    Orderlines *[]Orderline
}

type Orderline struct {
    Id int64
    Product *Product
    Amount int64
}

type Product struct {
    Id int64
    Modelnr string
    Price float64
}

func (o *Order) total_amount() float64 {
    return 0.0 // Total amount collector for each Orderline goes here
}

func main() {
    c := Customer{1, "Customername"}

    p1 := Product{30, "Z97", 9.95}
    p2 := Product{31, "Z98", 25.00}

    ol1 := Orderline{10, &p1, 2}
    ol2 := Orderline{11, &p2, 6}

    ols := []Orderline{&ol1, &ol2}

    o := Order{1, &c, &ols}

    fmt.Println(o)
}
```

I also tried to append to the Slice in the Order directly, but it also failed:

```
o := new(Order)
o.Id = 1
o.Customer = &c
append(o.Orderlines, &ol1, &ol2)
```

throws:

```
$ go run test.go 
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:48: append(o.Orderlines, &ol1, &ol2) evaluated but not used
```

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/N2Ulsh9uzO

Comment: @SethHoenig so a Slice of pointers `[]*Orderline` rather than a pointer to a Slice `*[]Orderline`?

Comment: @blesh Each Orderline needs to be it's original reference. I've updated my question. How could I get `append` to work in such fashion?

Comment: append returns a new slice, it doesn't modify the slice you pass in. (A slice is just pointers under the hood, so it's not like you're copying anything though).

 So line 48 should be: o.Orderliness =  append(o.Orderlines, &ol1, &ol2)

Comment: Thank you, that worked :). Can you post it as the answer? Then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to put Orderline pointers into a slice that wants Orderline values.

```
type Order struct {
    Id int64
    Customer *Customer
    Orderlines *[]Orderline
}
```

Change this field's type from

`Orderlines *[]Orderline`

to...

`Orderlines []*Orderline`

You also need to change...

`ols := []Orderline{&ol1, &ol2}`

to

`ols := []*Orderline{&ol1, &ol2}`

In most cases defining a *[]slicetype is redundant because slices, maps, and channels are already reference types. In otherwords if you pass the value of a slice defined in main into a function, changes made to the copied slice's indices will mutate the original slice defined in main as well.

However, it's important to note that slices become decoupled from each other when an individual copy's underlying array is forced to grow it's capacity as a result of appending data to your slice. Therefore in certain scenarios you may find a pointer to a slice ideal or even necessary.

Comment: Yes, this continues what Seth noted too. Thanks for the detailed explanation! I'm already a bit further in my code on this. And am also testing some RDBMS implementations to work best with my structure. I'm trying to rebuild a B2B Portal I've made in PHP a long time ago, so it's easier to have a solid base to work towards for a language I haven't worked that much with yet. Do you have any experience on how MySQL/Postgres impacts the general Go performance? I'm afraid that Go will suffer for the data-link (SQL) will be the weak link that slows Go down.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to look into some ORM solutions now (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647192/rdbms-impact-on-golang), but I have no comparison material yet when it comes to Go. I'm pretty perfectionistic and like to do more extensive research before starting with new tools :)