# RDBMS impact on Golang

Tags: sql, go, rdbms, database-performance

I'm not going to make a big long rattle on this question about what I've tested and number crunching. I'm more interested in actual up-to-date practice performances.

I've read tons of articles already and some of them are pretty skeptical or either very *pro to one library*. I'm currently testing a bit with `gorp`, yet I have no clue how to compare the performances of such a library towards others.

I know `gorp` is an extra layer that tries to add ORM to the basic SQL driver/implementation, but seeing Go's extremely clear code and being it very close to the bone on everything it does. It's not like with PHP/Python/JAVA what I'm used too, where you have to navigate through endless layers of complexity to actually see what a package does in its essence.

So my question is if anyone can share (benchmarks are always welcome :) ) their experience and knowledge on this subject.

I don't think a NoSQL-type solution is an option for my projects. All my projects always strongly depend on business logic and intertwined relationships. I also wonder if Postgres will be a win over MySQL. With Django (Python) I noticed significant performance gain using Postgres, but I never found prove on that matter if it was due to the Postgres core implementation or just Django's way of using the wrapper.

**Small update**

After rereading the question I noticed I kind of missed the actual goal of it. I'm actually looking for the most suitable SQL solution that will least slow down Golang itself. I know the SQL runs concurrent, but also concerning heavy traffic when running it as a web service. I won't be really bothered to drop the ORM part again if that will get me major gain on performance.

Comment: you would be _very_ hard pressed to notice any performance difference between any ORM and another.  What _can_ make a difference is the kind of queries that yo tend to use, and that can be influenced by the ORM style.

Comment: @javier thanks, that certainly sounds comforting. I'm kind of excited to see how much faster Go works when building a web service. It's kind of how I felt when I moved from CodeIgniter/DataMapper to Django for my personal projects. Go again gives that same feeling towards Django, while still not losing too much control and simplicity. Go was surprisingly simple to what I was used to with classical C variants.

Comment: @Javier sums it up well. Your queries will have the biggest impact on performance by far: good use of indexes, limits, etc will net you better gains than the choice of library. gorp is pretty nice for an "ORM", but if you want to look at simpler alternatives also consider https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx and/or https://github.com/eaigner/jet

Comment: Another thing that can make a difference is the total number of queries you perform.  If the ORM ends up doing many small queries where a few more expensive queries would do, that's going to impact performance.  The context switches and possible network traffic starts to add up.  For instance, if you want to update multiple rows in a table, will it perform a `SELECT` followed by multiple `UPDATE` queries, or can you get it to generate a single `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to use an ORM [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) or [gorp](https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp) are good Go options. Personally, I am a bit old school and I would rather for a given type `Foo`, I would rather write a `FooDB` struct that implements a `FooDS` interface. Everything in your app just uses `FooDS`. (DB = database, DS = datastore)

Your FooDB implementation could be using any number of underlying technologies MongoDB, LevelDB, SQL, etc and it can change as your app changes and this change is transparent to the rest of your app (since the rest of your app uses `FooDS`).

I would default to using [database/sql](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) (Prepared statements, etc) and the most mature Go SQL driver is Julien Schmidt's MySQL driver: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql